# ggplot bar chart does not show correctly on Shiny

Tags: r, ggplot2, shiny

When I create bar chart below in R, there was no problem but when I convert these code to shiny function, the problem is occur, could you help ?

Bar chart in normal R code:

```
path <- "WA_Fn-UseC_-HR-Employee-Attrition.csv (job attrition)"
data <-fread(path)
# bar chart function function
Categorical_vs_categorical_plot_2 <- function(data,group_col,fill_col){
  data %>%
    ggplot(aes_(x = fill_col, group = group_col)) + 
    geom_bar(aes(y = ..prop.., fill = factor(..x..)), 
             stat="count", 
             alpha = 0.7) +
    geom_text(aes(label = scales::percent(..prop..), y = ..prop.. ), 
              stat= "count", 
              vjust = 2) +
    labs(y = "Percentage", fill= "Education") +
    facet_grid(~Attrition) +
    theme_minimal()+
    theme(legend.position = "none", plot.title = element_text(hjust = 0.5)) + 
    ggtitle("Attrition") 
  
}

Categorical_vs_categorical_plot_2(data,~Attrition,~BusinessTravel)
```

[Normal bar chart](https://i.stack.imgur.com/R5Xvw.png)

Bar chart convert to shiny code [error occur, not show facet_grid and text value like normal bar chart above] :

```
      output$cat_vs_cat_chart2 <- renderPlot({
    data() %>%
      #ggplot(aes_(x = input$cat_compare, group = ~Attrition)) + 
      ggplot(aes_(x = 'BusinessTravel', group = ~Attrition)) +
      geom_bar(aes(y = ..prop.., fill = factor(..x..)), 
               stat="count", 
               alpha = 0.7) +
      geom_text(aes(label = scales::percent(..prop..), y = ..prop.. ), 
                stat= "count", 
                vjust = 2) +
      #labs(y = "Percentage", fill= "Education") +
      facet_grid(~Attrition) +
      theme_minimal()+
      theme(legend.position = "none", plot.title = element_text(hjust = 0.5)) + 
      ggtitle("Attrition") 
    
  })
```

[Error bar chart](https://i.stack.imgur.com/GaGB9.png)

Comment: Thank, I've add my answer as below!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[Update] I got answers by myself:

[version 1] If input column feature directly to bar chart: need to add ~ to each column feature:

```
      output$cat_vs_cat_chart2 <- renderPlot({
    data() %>%
      ggplot(aes_(x = ~BusinessTravel, group = ~Attrition)) +
      geom_bar(aes(y = ..prop.., fill = factor(..x..)), 
               stat="count", 
               alpha = 0.7) +
      geom_text(aes(label = scales::percent(..prop..), y = ..prop.. ), 
                stat= "count", 
                vjust = 2) +
      #labs(y = "Percentage", fill= "Education") +
      facet_grid(~Attrition) +
      theme_minimal()+
      theme(legend.position = "none", plot.title = element_text(hjust = 0.5)) + 
      ggtitle("Attrition") 
    
  })
```

[version 2] If input column feature from input$ in shiny ui : need to use aes_string instead aes_:

```
  output$cat_vs_cat_chart2 <- renderPlot({
    data() %>%
      ggplot(aes_string(x = input$cat_compare, group = "Attrition")) + 
      geom_bar(aes(y = ..prop.., fill = factor(..x..)), 
               stat="count", 
               alpha = 0.7) +
      geom_text(aes(label = scales::percent(..prop..), y = ..prop.. ), 
                stat= "count", 
                vjust = 2) +
      #labs(y = "Percentage", fill= "Education") +
      facet_grid(~Attrition) +
      theme_minimal()+
      theme(legend.position = "none", plot.title = element_text(hjust = 0.5)) + 
      ggtitle("Attrition") 
    
  })
```